# Clone Vertex in gremlin

Tags: javascript, clone, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am quite new in the gremlin and I am trying to clone a vertex with all of the properties it has but assigns different partition keys, does anyone knows a fast way to do that? I haven't found a simple answer to a question so far

Other than that, is it possible to copy the whole graph with the same partition key value?

Many thanks!

Comment: I can provide an answer of how to clone a vertex in Gremlin if that would help, but I am not familiar with how CosmosDB allocates partition keys.

Comment: In this link is how Azure cosmosDB works with partition key:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/graph-partitioning,hope this answer you, if you can provide the query to that clone, would be great